# Is there anyway to combine these 2 regex patterns into one?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these 2 patterns, to remove multiple hyphens or underscores in a replace, and replace them with just one, but seeing as there, basically the same, I was curious if I could combine them into one pattern.

```
url = url.replace(/([-]+)/g, '-');
url = url.replace(/([_]+)/g, '_');
```

I believe the actual pattern would just be `/([-_])/g`, but I can't think how to tell if it should be replaced with a hyphen or underscore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(-|_)+
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yA5iD9/7

Comment: I'm not sure why you we're downvoted for this answer, it seems perfectly fine to me!

Comment: @vks your regex won't work if `_` and `-` are in consecutive.

Comment: @vks others? who? You mean casimer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a backreference:

```
url = url.replace(/([-_])\1+/g, '$1');
```

Answer (score -1):

Pipe (`|`) operator is the OR function. Can you try this?

```
url = url.replace(/([-|_]+)/g, '-');
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I can only imagine because this replaces everything with hyphens, rather than hyphens or underscores depending on what was found.

Comment: @TomHart But this is the same as the one you accepted right?

Comment: The regex is, but the one I accepted also covers replace it with the correct character too.